# Running a PowerShell command using Ansible

Tags: ansible

I have some PowerShell commands to perform a job. Instead of running them one after another, I want to place them in an Ansible playbook so that they get executed in a sequence when the playbook is being run.

Any suggestions about which modules could I use in ansible to do this??

Comment: Is Ansible's documentation of any help? http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_windows.html#getting-to-powershell-3-0-or-higher

Comment: Yaaa...it is a good help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save the commands to a file and execute them using the [`script`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/script_module.html) module.

```
- script: PowerShell.ps1
```

Comment: Hey, I have done this....   - **script: 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\cpsm'** where cpsm is the name of the powershell file. But, I get the error that it is unable to find the file in the expected paths.

Comment: Did you read and understand this sentence from the manual "*The local script at path will be transferred to the remote node and then executed*"?

Comment: I am so sorry....Its my mistake...I solved it finally by placing the ps1 file in my linux controller machine. Thanxxx Techraf